# Awk strings enclosed in brackets

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to make a script to make reading logs easier. I'm having trouble extracting a string enclosed in brackets.

I want to extract the thread ID of a log which looks like this:

```
[CURRENT_DATE][THREAD_ID][PROCESS_NAME]Some random text here
```

I have tried this but it prints the `CURRENT_DATE`:

```
awk -F '[][]' '{print $2}'
```

If I use `print $3` it prints the `Some random text here` part.

Is there any way that I could somehow read the string enclosed in brackets?

Comment: An awk field separator can be either a single character or a regular expression. BTW, I suggest that you remove the _bash_ tag from your post, because the question is not really related to bash.

Comment: Which awk prints `Some random text here` using `print $3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? (Note that multiple character delimiters seem *not* to be available in GNU awk 4 respectively in the awk version the OP is using.)

```
pattern='[CURRENT_DATE][THREAD_ID][PROCESS_NAME]Some random text here'
echo $pattern

awk -F '[' '{print substr($3, 1, length($3)-2)}' <<< "$pattern"
```

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, this one works except that the outter bracket is printed, so it looks like

THREAD_ID]

Comment: I changed it to length($3)-2 so it looks like this
awk -F '[' '{print substr($3, 1, length($3)-2)}'

which doesn't print the ']' bracket anymore

am i doing this right?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk`:

```
s='[CURRENT_DATE][THREAD_ID][PROCESS_NAME]Some random text here'
awk -F '\\]\\[' '{print $2}' <<< "$s"
```

```
THREAD_ID
```

`-F '\\]\\['` will make text `][` as delimiter.

Comment: Hi, Ive tried this and it printed THREAD_ID]PROCESS_NAME]Some random text here.

I specifically am just trying to extract the THREAD_ID string

Comment: @anubhava weird, im trying to read from a log file logs.txt with many lines of the same formatting

so the way I tried yours is

awk -F '\\\]\\\[' '{print $2}' path/to/file > tmp.txt

When i open tmp.txt its just THREAD_ID][PROCESS_NAME]Some random text here'

Comment: What's your awk version?

Comment: Note that you need to double escape `]` and `[`.

Comment: Are there awk versions which do not support multiple character delimiters (Like `cut`)?

Comment: I have tested it on my OSX and GNU awk versions and both worked with `'\\]\\['`

Comment: I think it might be possible with GNU awk (The multiple character delimiter). I tested also on OSX and GNU awk. Unluckily I do not have regular awk available.

Comment: @anubhava Im running AWK v4.1.4

Im using the Ubuntu developer mode in Windows where Im running my bash scripts from

Comment: @jdoecs420: Can you try my answer with single character delimiter?

Comment: @jdoecs420, Could you please try my solution once too and lemme know if that helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Different versions of awk behave in different ways. Without knowing what you're running, it's difficult to say why your existing code behaves as it does.

You already know that with a field separator of `[][]` or just `[`, you have an empty field at the beginning of each line. Instead, I'd try this:

```
awk -F']' '{gsub(/\[/,""); print $2}' input.log
```

This simply strips out the left-square-bracket and uses its fellow as your field delimiter. The advantage of using `]` instead of `[` is that it makes $1 your first field.